# Hibernate 4 automatically delete many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I update hibernate from 3.5.6 to 4.10, I have a problem with many-to-many relationship:

**User Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade(value={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH}) 
    @JoinTable(name="usersroles", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name ="usersroles_user" )}, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "usersroles_role") }) 
    @JSON(serialize=false)
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
}
```

**Role Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="role")
public class Role {  
    @ManyToMany(cascade {CascadeType.REFRESH},fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="roles")
    @JSON(serialize=false)
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
}
```

That is a **query method**:

```
public List<User> getUserAndRoleList() {
    String jpql = "SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User u , Role r, UserRole ur  WHERE u.id = ur.userId AND r.id = ur.roleId ORDER BY u.username";
    QueryResult<User> qr = super.getDataWithOriginalJPQL(jpql);

    userList = qr.getResultList();
    return userList;
}
```

When I want to get the Role:

```
userList = userService.getUserAndRoleList();
for(int i=0;i<userList.size();i++){
    Iterator<Role> it = userList.get(i).getRoles().iterator();
    Role role ;
}
```

This works. But when code executes

```
userList.get(i).getRoles()
```

Hibernate 4.1  will automatically delete User and Role relationship in usersroles table. But with Hibernate 3.6.5, it didn't delete the relationship.

In fact, I don't delete anything at all and I don't ask hibernate to delete anything. Something that I don't understand might occur. How do I prevent Hibernate from deleting? Or is there anything that I did wrong?

Comment: You know you can use the select statement like this: "SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User u join fetch u.roles ORDER BY u.username" with same results?

Comment: Thanks!It works!When i change the jpql that you gave to me .Hibernate doesn't automatically delete User and Role relationship record any more.But I still have a question:why hibernate will automatically delete the relationship if use "SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User u , Role r, UserRole ur  WHERE u.id = ur.userId AND r.id = ur.roleId ORDER BY u.username"?